# If and else "==" not working

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to show different text on WordPress based on a value from a select box. I have written an "if and else" statement but it isn't working for some weird reason. Here is my code:

```
<?php global $wpUserStylesheetSwitcher;$wpUserStylesheetSwitcher->show_wp_user_stylesheet_switcher(array('list_title'=>'Change theme', 'show_list_title'=>'true', 'list_type'=>'blogstyle'));
                    $gdgt_theme = '<script>var yourSelect = document.getElementById( "gdgt-test" );document.write( yourSelect.options[ yourSelect.selectedIndex ].value )</script>';
                echo $gdgt_theme;
                if ($gdgt_theme == 0) { ?>
                    <article class="gdgt-article">
                <div class="gdgt-loop-post">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="gdgt-loop-thumb">
                            <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('gdgt_loop_thumb');
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<img src="http://for-b.tk/_ph/13/934023873.gif" title="Image not available yet" alt="image-coming-soon"/>';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="loop-overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gdgt-post-meta">
                            <h1><?php echo the_title_limit(70, '…'); ?></h1>    
                    </a>
                            <div class="gdgt-article-meta">
                                by <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?> - <?php echo the_time(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gdgt-post-excerpt">
                                <?php echo "test" ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </article>
                <?php }

                else {
                ?>
                    <article class="gdgt-article">
                <div class="gdgt-loop-post">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo the_title(); ?>">
                        <div class="gdgt-loop-thumb">
                            <?php
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('gdgt_loop_thumb');
                            }
                            else {
                                echo '<img src="http://for-b.tk/_ph/13/934023873.gif" title="Image not available yet" alt="image-coming-soon"/>';
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="loop-overlay"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="gdgt-post-meta">
                            <h1><?php echo the_title_limit(70, '…'); ?></h1>    
                    </a>
                            <div class="gdgt-article-meta">
                                by <?php the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); ?> - <?php echo the_time(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gdgt-post-excerpt">
                                <?php echo "else works"; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </article>
                <?php }
              ?>
```

**Code Explanation:** First I try to get the value from the select box using a simple JS code. I then `echo` it so that I can see it is returning the correct value. Then I run the `if` and `else`

**The Problem:** When the value == 0, the "test" text shows up, but when it isn't equal to 0, the text "test" still shows up. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Please help.

Comment: @Mihai Tried it, doesn't work. It returns the "else works" string every time (even if it equals 0)

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the code executed on the client-cide and the code executed on the server-side?